# What is the Probability density function of $X^2$ where X is an Uniform distribution

Tags: random-variables, uniform-distribution, density-function, expected-value

I'm a student and I'm studying random variables and very new to it. I was studying the [Uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) and in it, it calculates the Expected of  $X^2$  by $$ E\left(X^2\right) =  \int_{- \infty}^\infty  x^2 p(x) dx $$
I understand the calculation of it, but if the [Probability density function plot](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/96/Uniform_Distribution_PDF_SVG.svg) of $X$ is like that (I fully understand that) I can't imagine the Probability density function of the $X^2$ because if we span the Probability density function of $X$ which is within $[a,b]$ to $[a^2,b^2]$ then the integral of $\int_{a^2}^{b^2} p(\sqrt x) dx$ may not be equal to 1 I guess.

Could you help me figure out what is the Probability density function of  $X^2$?

Comment: I actually computed the pdf of $X^2$ for a general random variable here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3043502/90543

Comment: @jgon thank you. it was hard for me to understand your answer because I'm very new to it, but finally, I get it. so I was right, it is not that simple that in the basic tutorials they just integral $\int_{- \infty}^\infty  x^2 p(x) d_x $ to find the Expected. nice answer.