# Law of the unconscious statistician

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I never knew that there was a formal name (Law of Unconscious Statistician) for something that I've used for awhile now, but probably for the wrong reasons.

Say we have a discrete random variable $X$ with a probability mass function $p(X=x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$.

To compute $E[X^2]$, I always always done
$$
(x_1)^2p(x_1) + \cdots (x_n)^2p(x_n)
$$
Which is using the law of unconscious statistician, but I actually applied this because I thought $p(x_i) = p(x_i^2)$. This isn't generally true right? By knowing the probability distribution of a random variable, is there any intuition we can get about the distribution of $f(X)$? In this case $f(X) = X^2$.

Comment: The statement $p(x_i) = p(x_i^2)$ doesn't really make sense. What you probably mean is something like $p(x_i = a) = p(x_i^2 = a^2)$.

Comment: An old question of mine got at this, and the answers are helpful.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3043490/reconciling-two-interpretations-of-ex2

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Wait, why? I defined $x_i$ to be a possible value of $X$. So when I wrote $p(x_i) = p(x_i^2)$, I really meant $p(X=x_i) = p(X^2=x_i^2)$.

I actually feel like I've seen the former notation (without the $X=$) more often.

Comment: @Randall Thanks I'll check that out.

Comment: @dd22205 If $p(a)$ is meant as a shorthand for $p(X = a)$, then $p(x_i^2)$ would be interpreted as $p(X = x_i^2)$, not $p(X^2 = x_i^2)$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh, I understand now what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The discrete case has an easy proof, see the [wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician#Discrete_case).  The two different summations are equal because they just collect the same terms differently.  It is the continuous case that needs a rigorous proof.

As to your $p(x)$ vs $p(x^2)$ issue, Omnomnonom is right that your notation is bad.  Aside from notation though, you cannot say:

$$Prob(X = x_1) = Prob(X^2 = x_1^2) \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{[This is wrong]}$$

because this simply is false.  Instead, you need

$$Prob(X^2 = x_1^2) = Prob(X = x_1) + Prob(X = -x_1)$$

Now of course your summation itself is correct, and this kind of "collecting of terms" is exactly what happens in the short proof in the wikipedia section.

Comment: Could you clarify where $Prob(X^2=x_1^2) = Prob(X=x_1) + Prob(X=-x_1)$ came from?

Comment: Basic arithmetic says $X^2=x_1^2$ iff $X=x_1$ or $X=-x_1$...